# Open a second file in a loop

Tags: python, path

I have a question about my script. I write a code which loop automatically on a list of input files. This list is a text file like that :

> E:\New_Fields\Field230_traitement_1.fits
>
> E:\New_Fields\Field235_traitement_1.fits
>
> E:\New_Fields\Field214_traitement_1.fits
>
> ...

My script reads this file and processes each file in the list :

```
with open("C:\Users\Valentin\Desktop\Stage M2\liste_traiteXY.txt", "r") as f :
    
    fichier_entier = f.read()
    files = fichier_entier.split("\n")

for fichier in files :
    
    with open(fichier, 'r') :
 
                outname = filename.replace('dereddenedXY.fits', 'Distribution_etoiles.png')
                outname2 = filename.replace('dereddenedXY.fits', 'Carte_densite_nonlisse.png')
                outname3 = filename.replace('dereddenedXY.fits', 'Carte_densite_lisse.png')
                outname6 = filename.replace('dereddenedXY.fits', 'Histogramme2D_heatmap.png')
                outname7 = filename.replace('dereddenedXY.fits', 'Masque_brut.png')
                outname8 = filename.replace('dereddenedXY.fits', 'Masque_convolue.png')
                outname10 = filename.replace('dereddenedXY.fits', 'SN_map.png')
                outname11 = filename.replace('dereddenedXY.fits', 'Histogramme_SN_map.png')
                outname12 = filename.replace('dereddenedXY.fits', 'SN_map_final.png')
                outname15 = filename.replace('dereddenedXY.fits', 'resume.png')
                    
        print "Fichier traité\n : " + fichier
        reading = fits.open(fichier)           # Ouverture du fichier à l'aide d'astropy
 
        tbdata = reading[1].data               # Lecture des données fits      

# PROCESS
```

But, during the process, I need to open a new input file where the path is given as following :

> filename =  'E:\New_Fields\Field169_mask.fits'

I don't want to make a list of mask files because the order is not the same that the first list. My question is how I can open the mask which corresponding with the processing file ?

For example, the first input file is : Field230_traitement_1.fits so I want to upload in the loop the file : Field230_mask.fits. Then, make the same thing with the file Field235 etc ...

Hopefully being clear :)

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily check if the first part of the two filenames are the same.

```
file1 = 'E:\New_Fields\Field230_traitement_1.fits'
file2 = 'E:\New_Fields\Field169_mask.fits'

if file1.split('\')[-1].split('_')[0] ==  file2.split('\')[-1].split('_')[0]:
    print('the files are related')
```

In this case, the names are different so the body of the if statement will not be executed.

Here a better way to iterate all the files in a folder using `glob`.

```
import glob

associatedFiles = {}
for fileName in glob.glob('E:\\New_Fields\\*.*'):
    fileID = fileName.split('\\')[-1].split('_')[0]
    if fileID not in associatedFiles:
        associatedFiles[fileID] = [fileName]
    else:
        associatedFiles[fileID].append(fileName)
```

`associatedFiles` is a dictionary having the common part of the filename as key and a list of related files as value.

P.S. I am on a Unix machine and I need to use `'\\'` instead of `'\'`. I am not sure if on Windows it is the same if something goes wrong try using `'\'`.

Comment: And how it's possible to associate the good file 2 (mask) with the file 1 (traitement) ? That's to say, take automatically `Field230_mask.fits` if it's `Field230_traitement_1.fits`, take `Field158_mask.fits` if it's `Field158_traitement_1.fits` etc ...

Comment: If the names are predictable there are no problems, in your case the name is `'FieldXXX' + '_' + 'traitement_1'` or  `+ 'mask'`. So, using split() you can extract `'FieldXXX'` . Once you have that, the mask file will be `'FieldXXX' + '_' + 'mask'` and the traitement file will be `'FieldXXX' + '_' + 'traitement_1'`

Comment: Ok thank you to your answer ! I will try your idea and I will come back if I get problems ;) I make the question as solved to the moment ;)

Comment: I have added a simple snippet that can help you out. Is not meant to be pythonic but will do the job and it's fairly readable.

Comment: I splitted the first input file in order to get `FieldXXX` and when I want to upload the mask, I wrote `filename2 =  'E:\New_Fields\' + fieldname + '_mask.fits'`. I think that I get a syntax error

Comment: yes, try like this `filename2 = 'E:\\New_Fields\\' + fieldname + '_mask.fits'`